# ForeignKey field problem with assign instance in form.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Here I want to save data from a form.py on my page (everything works well from the admin panel).

my model.py is,

```
class contrat(models.Model):
    contrtID     = models.CharField(max_length=25,unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.contrtID
```

and the other table;

```
class Invoices(models.Model):
    Invoce_Titl    = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Cntrat_Nbr     = models.ForeignKey(contrat, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #should be Actived
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Invoce_Titl
```

and the form I use is:

```
query_contrat = (('', '-------'),)
class Invoices_F(forms.ModelForm):
    Invoce_Titl     = forms.CharField(label='Invoice Title',max_length=50)
    Cntrat_Nbr      = forms.ChoiceField(label='Contract ID',choices=query_contrat)
    class Meta:
        model= Invoices
        fields=('Invoce_Titl','Cntrat_Nbr')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Invoices_F, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Cntrat_Nbr'].choices = query_contrat + tuple( contrat.objects.filter(Actived='Active').values_list('id','contrtID'))
```

So when I try in the HTML page it gives me this error when I press save data.

Cannot assign "'5'": "Invoices.Cntrat_Nbr" must be a "contrat" instance.

So my from is taking the contrat.id as a string with another ' ', so how I do get rid of this problem?

Comment: Please use a `ModelChoiceField`, this makes it a lot easier to select a model object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has a form field for that: a [**`ModelChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField):

```
class Invoices_F(forms.ModelForm):
    Invoce_Titl = forms.CharField(label='Invoice Title',max_length=50)
    Cntrat_Nbr = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        required=False,
        label='Contract ID',
        queryset=contrat.objects.filter(Actived='Active')
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model= Invoices
        fields=('Invoce_Titl','Cntrat_Nbr')
```

This will make selecting a `contrat` model object more elegant and with less boilerplate code.